# WebView no carga algunas paginas

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una activity con solo un webview, estoy tratando de cargar una pagina diferente, justo después de que se halla cargado la anterior, para ello estoy usando `onPageFinished` . Para detectar que la pagina se cargó y luego cargar las paginas que siguen.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var posget:Int = 0

    var urlone:String =  "https://youtube.com"
    var urltwo:String = "https://facebook.com"
    var urltree:String = "https://lottiefiles.com/featured"
    var urlfour:String = "https://instagram.com"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val setting: WebSettings = webVarss.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true


        webVarss.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){
        }
        webVarss.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                Log.i("webs","load")
                if (posget == 1){
                    Log.i("webpos","1 -load2")
                    posget = 2    //Si comento esto, si se muestra la pagina que deberia ("pag1")
                    webVarss.loadUrl(urltwo)
                }
                if (posget == 2){
                    Log.i("webpos","2 -load3")
                    posget = 3     //Si comento esto, si se muestra la pagina que deberia ("pag2")
                    webVarss.loadUrl(urltree)

                }
                if (posget == 3){
                    Log.i("webpos","3 -load4")
                    posget = 4
                    webVarss.loadUrl(urlfour)
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i("webs","first")
        webVarss.loadUrl(urlone)
        posget = 1

    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webVarss"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error**
Pasa que, cuando ejecuto la app solo me muestra la primera pagina  y la ultima , es decir las paginas 2 y 3 , no se muestran.
He revisado el logcat y todo se ejecuta como debería sin embargo como dije anteriormente, solo carga la primera pagina luego que termina de cargar se muestra la ultima, obviando las 2° y 3° pagina.

**NOTA**
Coloque un `Thread.sleep(2000)`, en el `onPageFinished` ,y  me di cuenta que esto hace que la primera pagina no se cargue o termine de cargar por completo, cosa que pienso no tendría sentido, ya que en el `onPageFinished` , ya se abría finalizado la carga de la pagina, puede que el error este relacionado con ello.

Talvez parezca que no tiene sentido cargar paginas de esa manera, sin embargo realmente necesito lograr ese comportamiento, eso es todo el código del proyecto.
Si tienen una idea diferente de como lograr eso compártanla por favor.

Comment: y donde defines `webVarss`? Este no es todo el código del proyecto

Comment: Olvide agregar mi xml, ya lo hice

Comment: cuantas malas prácticas.. Qué forma de nombrar las variables es esa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error está acá:

```
if (posget == 1){
    ...
    posget = 2
}
if (posget == 2){
    ...
    posget = 3
}
if (posget == 3) ...
```

el valor que le asignas a la variable hace que la siguiente condición siempre sea verdadera, por lo tanto se ejecutan todos los bloques.

La solución es usar `else if` o simplemente `when`

```
when (posget) {
    1 -> {
        webVarss.loadUrl(urltwo)
        posget = 2
    }
    2 -> {
        webVarss.loadUrl(urltree)
        posget = 3
    }
    3 -> {
        webVarss.loadUrl(urlfour)
        posget = 4
    }
}
```

Aunque lo ideal sería guardar las url en un array y simplemente cargar el siguiente índice

Comment: Las dos respuestas funcionan, gracias.